# Tornar aplicação JavaScript de paradigma procedural para orientação a objetos

Tags: javascript, html

No inicio de meus estudos em JavaScript, fiz uma aplicação simples de um estoque de supermercado, onde o cliente poderia pesquisar um determinado produto e ver se ainda estava em estoque ou tinha acabado. Construída em paradigma procedural.

```
let mercado = Array();

mercado['frutas'] = Array('banana', 'maçã', 'laranja', 'goiaba');
mercado['sucos'] = Array('tang', 'mit', 'fit');
mercado['higienicos'] = Array('papel higienico', 'escova de dente', 'creme dental');


function pesquisar() {
    let digitado = document.getElementById('pesquisa');
    digitado = digitado.value;
    digitado = digitado.toLowerCase();

    let fruta = mercado['frutas'].indexOf(digitado);
    let suco = mercado['sucos'].indexOf(digitado);
    let higienicos = mercado['higienicos'].indexOf(digitado);

    if(fruta != -1){
        alert("Temos essa fruta");
    } else if (suco != -1) {
        alert("Temos esse suco");
    } else if (higienicos != -1) {
        alert("Temos esse higiênico");
    } else {
        alert("Não temos esse produto em nosso estoque");
    }
}
```

Prosseguindo com os estudos, descobri o paradigma de orientação a objetos, então, para prática-lo resolvi passar essa aplicação de procedural a OO, e surgiu o problema, ela não funcionou!

```
class ListaEstoque {
    constructor(){
        this.frutas = Array('banana', 'maçã', 'laranja', 'goiaba');
        this.sucos = Array('tang', 'mit', 'fit');
        this.higienicos = Array('papel higienico', 'escova de dentes', 'creme dental');
    }
    pesquisar(){
        let digitado = document.getElementById('pesquisa');
        digitado = digitado.value;
        digitado = digitado.toLowerCase();

        let fruta = this.frutas.indexOf(digitado);
        let suco = this.sucos.indexOf(digitado);
        let higienicos = this.indexOf(digitado);

        if(fruta != -1){
            alert("Temos essa fruta");
        } else if (suco != -1) {
            alert("Temos esse suco");
        } else if (higienicos != -1) {
            alert("Temos esse higiênico");
        } else {
            alert("Não temos esse produto em nosso estoque");
        }
    }
}

let y = new ListaEstoque();

function pesquisar(){
    y.pequisar();
}
```

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Treino</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="script_OO.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Mercado</h1>
        <p>Use nossa aplicação para saber se o produto ainda está em estoque!</p>

        <form id="formulário" method="POST">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="campo" id="pesquisa">
            <input type="submit" value="pesquisar" onclick="pesquisar()">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Em que ponto estou errando? como resolve-lo?

Comment: O que mais está errando é achar que OOP fará seu código ficar melhor. OOP é uma das coisas mais difíceis que existe, e quase todo mundo faz errado e pior, sem um domínio e comprometimento muito grande, é melhor nem tentar. Precisa de muito estudo e experiência para fazer certo.

Comment: Pode parecer frustrante mas jogar umas classes e instanciar uns objetos dentro do código não o torna Orientado a Objetos. Ele continua a ser Imperativo ou Funcional só que com Objetos. A orientação só é atingida respeitando determinados princípios, métodos, padrões e postulados de implementação e design.